# Django 1.9 JSONfield stored dictionary returns unicode instead

Tags: python, django

We've just upgraded to Django 1.9 and moved things to its built-in JSONfield, which we use to store a dictionary. However, when I try to read data from it, it returns unicode of the dictionary instead.

My JSONfield is defined as:

```
class SmsInfo(models.Model):
    [...] 
    json = JSONField(default=dict)
```

Data is written to it by:

```
params = dict(request.POST)
SmsInfo.objects.create([...], json=params, [...])
```

It is later read in this way:

```
incoming_smsses = SmsInfo.objects.select_related('game').defer('game__serialized').filter([...])
```

At which point:

```
 print incoming_smsses[0].json.__class__
```

returns

```
<type 'unicode'>
```

instead of the dict I am expecting and my code crashes because it can't look up any keys.

I've been stuck on this for quite a bit, and I can't figure out why this is going wrong. I've used literal_eval as a workaround for now, which turns the unicode back into a dict. That works for now, but I'd rather tackle this at the source!

Why is my dictionary being turned to unicode here?

Comment: What version of Postgres and psycopg are you using?

Comment: I am using Postgres 9.5 and psycopg 2.6.1, which I think should be okay as the documentation specifies PostgreSQL ≥ 9.4 and Psycopg2 ≥ 2.5.4.

Comment: Hmm. What happens if you query SmsInfo directly without the select_related/defer stuff?

Comment: I've tried before just querying SmsInfo.objects.all() in case that was a problem, but I got the same result, unicode from the json field.

Comment: Late comment, but... I wan't having any issues on 2.7.x.  Upgraded everything to 3.5.x and _now_ I get that same issue.  No clue what happened.

Comment: This has been reported as a bug - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27675

Comment: was this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I just went through upgrading from a third-party JSONField to the native postgres JSONField and found through psql that the column type is still `text`.

So on psql, confirm your column type:

```
\d+ table_name
```

And alter the column if it's still text:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE jsonb USING column_name::jsonb;
```

Comment: FANTASTIC fix, thank you. I had the same issue when I upgraded Django. In Django 1.8.14, I had "from jsonfield.fields import JSONField".
In Django 1.9.13, I have "from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField".
For some reason, when I returned type(mymodel.jsonvalues) was <type 'unicode'> instead of <type 'dict'>.
Your one-liner in psql fixed it; now type(mymodel.jsonvalues) == <type 'unicode'> again.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by erickw in comments, this has been filed as a bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27675

If you happened to use `django-jsonfield` before, there is a conflict between them, thus as the bug above suggests, the solution is to completely **delete and remake the migration files** of the app which uses the jsonfield.

In that case, apparently you would like to uninstall `django-jsonfield` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Django 1.11 and postgres 11.4.

Passing list of python dicts to JSONField worked for me:

```
data_python = []
for i in range(3):
    entry = {
        'field1': value1,
        'field2': 999,
        'field3': 'aaaaaaaaaa',
        'field4': 'never' 
    }
    data_python.append(entry)
MyModel.objects.create(data=data_python, name='DbEntry1')
```

My guess is that for dicts this should work as well

And my model is:

```
class MetersWithNoReadings(models.Model):
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    data = JSONField()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @stelios points out, this is a [bug with `django-jsonfield`](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-jsonfield/issues/5) which is not compatible with the native version.

Either:

- uninstall `django-jsonfield` (if it is no longer required as a project dependency, you can check with `pipdeptree`), or
- upgrade to `django-jsonfield >= 1.3.0` since the issue is now closed and the fix merged.

Answer (score -2):

Seems related to DB storage here. Still this JSONField acts as a validator for proper JSON formatting.

However, you can hack around and load a dict from this returned unicode string.

Try as follow :

```
import json
data = json.loads(incoming_smsses[0].json)
```

Then you can access it as a dict IMO.

Comment: Thanks. I've already gotten my code working too, I used literal_eval to achieve the same result as you did here. The issue is there's still something wrong with the value coming out of the db different than it's going in, and I'd like to nail this down before we use Django 1.9 and Postgres 9.5 in production.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use native postgres JSONField

```
from django.contrib.postgres import fields

class Some_class(models.Model):
    json = fields.JSONField()
```

Comment: This is the field I am using and having the problem with, unfortunately.

Comment: Possibly there is no jsonb in your database, but rather json (meaning a pure string, no binary representation). I had this problem due to the Django Rest Framework, where the serializer is not set to binary=True by default.
Storing jsonb gives you a python dict whereas the json-string stays a string that has to be parsed according to the previous answers.

Comment: @BumbleBee I have the same issue. I'm using `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` and the column type in the database is `JSONB`.

Comment: @hheimbuerger Did you have a look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield and set JSONField(binary=True) accordingly?

We adjusted the attribute in a serializer. Unfortunately I can't find that right now and I don't remember why. Maybe, the contrib-JSONField does not support the binary attribute? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: @BumbleBee I'm not using Django REST Framework, and for all we know, neither is the OP. This is about the ORM JSONField not about API serialization. So not sure what that has to do with the original question.